# python pyramid, render user dashboard at root url when logged in

Tags: python, pyramid

How is it possible within a pyramid app to render a logged in users dashboard at the root url? When not logged in the root url shows a sign in form.

After searching I've only found examples for other frameworks.

Comment: I don't know pyramid well, but I would assume you just have a statement within the route function that says something like, "if the user is logged in, render this template. else, render some other template."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='dashboard.jinja2')
def home_view(request):
    if request.authenticated_userid is None:
        # most people would probably opt to redirect to the login url
        # here instead of rendering a response, but you asked
        return render_to_response('login.jinja2', {}, request=request)
    # user is logged in, so use the dashboard renderer
    return {}
```

HOWEVER, pyramid is cool and has predicates. Neat. So we can use the `effective_principals` predicate to dispatch between 2 different views based on whether the user is logged in:

```
from pyramid.security import Authenticated

@view_config(route_name='home', effective_principals=Authenticated, renderer='dashboard.jinja2')
def dashboard_view(request):
    return {}

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='login.jinja2')
def login_from_home_view(request):
    return {}
```

Comment: +1 to this more advanced Pyramid answer. The predicates are such a better way to keep your code clean and make for much more locked down security. IE you can't accidentally grant incorrect access in a view by a bug in a conditional check, your protected view just won't ever execute.

Answer (score 1):

A rewrite of the [SQLAlchemy + URL dispatch wiki tutorial](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/master/tutorials/wiki2/index.html) includes an example application that does what you want, plus password hashing, authorization, and tests. This will be released in Pyramid 1.7 (1.6.1 is the current version as of this writing). You can grab the complete source of the app in the tutorial from the [src](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid/tree/master/docs/tutorials/wiki2/src/tests/tutorial) directory of the tutorial.